# Possible tags for Common-Law and Civil-law jurisdictions

Tags: discussion, tags

I know there is some debate on whether legal reasoning should be subject matter for this site; however, when responding to what a court can do, it depends on the legal system of that country. Legal systems, in general, can be broken up into two main categories, common law and civil law countries.

Should there be tags to make this distinction? It might help people trying to find an answer on reasoning and the impact of prior cases on future cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are tags:

[common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law) refers to common law jurisdictions like Commonwealth countries and (most) of the USA.

[civil-legal-system](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-legal-system) refers to European and related jurisdictions (including Louisiana). This should not be confused with [civil-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-law) which, confusingly, refers to non-criminal law in [common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law) jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous question, tags can be created as questions require them. If you ask, or see, a question that would benefit from being distinguished as [common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law) rather than [civil-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-law), go for it.

Comment: Right. I asked this before your response there. Additionally at the time I didn't have the rep needed yet

Comment: I see. Also, I believe tags can't be created in isolation (or at least, not easily) and they'd self-delete after a period of time if unused, so tagging questions with new tags is really the best way to go.

Comment: As currently configured the [tag:civil-law] means civil (i.e. not criminal) law in [tag:common-law] jurisdictions.

Comment: It could also be useful to make note of the legal system in the excerpt of the jurisdiction tags